# Stored Procedure Not Returning Result from C# Code, but It Returns Value when Executed as Query

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, return-value

I have written stored procedure to get customer id with given inputs. 
  When executed manually it returns value but not returning any value from 
  C# code.

```
    create  procedure getCustomerID 
    @firstname CHAR(25),
    @lastname CHAR(25),
    @middlename as CHAR(25)=null,
    @DOB datetime,
    @CustomerState as CHAR(25)=null,
    @CustomerNumber INTEGER,
    @ID nvarchar(25) output
    as

    begin
    ....
    ...
    set @ID='something'
    end



    USE [TestDB]
    GO
    declare @ID nvarchar(25) 
    EXECute [dbo].[getCustomerID] 
    'A', 'B','C','1963-09-06','', 12345, @ID out
     print 'ID:'+@ID
    GO
```

OUTPUT

> ID: CN0075
>
> ---

C# code:

```
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Connectionstring"))
            {
                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    conn.Open();
                }
                using (var command = new SqlCommand("getCustomerID", conn)
                {
                    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                })
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("@firstname", SqlDbType.Char, 25).Value = "A";
                command.Parameters.Add("@lastname", SqlDbType.Char, 25).Value = "B";
                command.Parameters.Add("@middlename", SqlDbType.Char, 25).Value = "C";
                command.Parameters.Add("@CustomerState", SqlDbType.Char, 25).Value = "";
                command.Parameters.Add("@DOB", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = "1963-09-06";
                command.Parameters.Add("@CustomerNumber", SqlDbType.Int).Value = "12345";
                command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 25).Direction = 
                ParameterDirection.Output;
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string retunID = command.Parameters["@ID"].Value.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
        catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.Error(e.Message);
    }
```

It does not throw exception. It executes the the stored procedure and does 
  not go inside `While(reader.read())` loop and read data.

Comment: White space is a wonderful thing, and hugely improves the readability of your code. I strongly recommend that you stop writing code that is all left aligned and start using indentation.

Comment: What is the error message in the exception?

Comment: Why are you reading the param in a loop? - its only ever going to have one value.  Use .ExecuteNonQuery() if your USP is not returning rows & then you don't need the reader.

Comment: No error . It goes through execute block but doesnt go inside the while(reader.read())

Comment: .Read is only going to work if you select rows - this is unrelated to output params.

Comment: No error?  Why do you say "It does throw exception."?

Comment: @AlexK. I am returning some string from SP. It will return only one string value

Comment: @TabAlleman sorry typo

Comment: @AlexK. How do I read the output string returned from SP

Comment: Replace the whole `using (SqlDataReader reader ...` block with `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` then  call `string retunID = command.Parameters["@ID"].Value.ToString();`

Comment: @AlexK. returnID values is still null

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks. Its working. it was problem with runtime data . lastname had ' in between (O'NEIL).command.ExecuteNonQuery() works.

Answer (score 0):

in your sp use **select** instate of **print**

```
create  procedure getCustomerID 
@firstname CHAR(25),
@lastname CHAR(25),
@middlename as CHAR(25)=null,
@DOB datetime,
@CustomerState as CHAR(25)=null,
@CustomerNumber INTEGER,
@ID nvarchar(25) output
as

begin
....
...
set @ID='something'
select @ID
end



USE [TestDB]
GO
declare @ID nvarchar(25) 
EXECute [dbo].[getCustomerID] 
'A', 'B','C','1963-09-06','', 12345, @ID out
 select 'ID:'+@ID
GO
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qjp0T.png)

Comment: problem is not with sql execute query. I am facing issue in c# code